# How to perform segue to a nib from storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, nib

I have 90% of my current project done in storyboard but I am also using a single xib view controller for an "enter your pin" view because this is the way it was integrated in a github project that I imported into my project. I need to segue from the xib back to storyboard. Going from storyboard to the xib was easy with a push method but now I would like to modal to another view in storyboard. Any suggestions? First, I tried to convert the xib to a view in storyboard but I failed as it was designed to work with nibs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new instance of any view controller on the storyboard by calling its instantiate method.

So do something like:

```
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the ViewController you need from your storyboard (therefor you need to set an identifier for the viewcontroller in the storyboard

```
ViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```

Then segue to this controller

```
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```