# "pushViewController" to own class followed by "performSegueWithIdentifier" resulting in "Receiver has no segue with identifier"

Tags: ios, view, controller, push, segue

I have this main menu view controller -thing, that, rather than being defined twice in my storyboard, with segues in between, calls `pushViewController` on a new instance of its own class. So it goes:

```
menu_a --> menu_a --> option_x
```

rather than

```
menu_a --> menu_b --> option_x
```

After pushing the view controller once, the `navigationController` loses track of the associated segues and I get the "Receiver has no segue with identifier" message. That is,

```
menu_a --> option_y
```

never produces this sort of error.

I've Googled and searched Stack Overflow for the past three hours with no luck.
I hope somebody out there has tried the same thing, and will want to elaborate on a workaround.

Comment: Congratulations on your first post! It's much easier for others to help you if you provide concrete specifics about your question, including things such a source code and screenshots. While you do present a good high level description of your problem, you could improve your question by including, e.g. more specific terminiology than "main menu view controller -thing"; the actual source code where you instantiate and push the new view controller; and any solutions you found already that were not helpful. Hope this helps you get your question answered!

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee this will work, but here goes:

Presumably because segues are a Storyboard feature, calling performSegue is referring back to your ViewController that was instantiated by the storyboard. As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076393/how-to-perform-segue-to-a-nib-from-storyboard), it's possible to request your storyboard to instantiate a new ViewController from itself, rather than creating it manually (which is what I presume you're doing).

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIViewController* dest = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomController"];
```

Attempting a segue from a ViewController created this way may have more luck, as it should have the same segue information associated, while a manually created one wouldn't). It's just a theory - let me know if it works :)

Comment: That looks like a much nicer solution than the (hopefully) temporary one I have chosen: I created an invisible button on the view controller on the story board, and it's allowed to start a segue to the parent view controller. I just trigger that segue by its identifier, and thus it still retains the other available segues. (It's still hackish to use a button - I'll try your method tomorrow! Many Thanks.)